# urllib2.urlopen(z).read() - try for x seconds then move to the next item

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I have a list of x websites from which I want to scrape data. 
Code:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

def checkurl(z):
    print urllib2.urlopen('http://'+z).read()

for x in t2w: #t2w is my list
    print x
    checkurl(x)
    print "\n"
```

As of now, the whole process stops, as soon as a website is
unavailable. What can I do to let urllib2 try for x time, give an error e.g "website not available' and then move on to the next item in the list.

Maybe should have mentioned that this is for .onion

```
import socks
import socket
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150)

socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

#####
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

def checkurl(z):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("http://"+z, timeout=1).read()
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        raise MyException("Error raised: %r" % e)
    #print urllib2.urlopen('http://'+z).read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeout` parameter.

```
try:
    urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com", timeout=1)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    raise MyException("Error raised: %r" % e)
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
>   for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.